# Attribute routing default url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

I have the following method in my controller, using C# MVC with Attribute roouting:

```
[Route("")]
[Route("/something-else")]
public IActionResult Index(){

}
```

Im using two different routes to access this functionallity, since i want customers with bookmarks to the previous implementation to work. 
The problem is that i cant specify which of these Routes will be the default one when i issue the action like this:

```
<a asp-controller="FOO" asp-action="Index">
```

Everythiing works as expected, both URLs work, but i cant specify which of these routes will be used when navigated to by the action, via the action above. 
I would like that the first route be used everytime i navigate to this action, except when someone explicitly writes the old url into the browser.

Are there any default attributes to the [Route("")] tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`RouteAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.0) class has an [`Order`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routeattribute.order?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_RouteAttribute_Order) property. From the docs:

> Gets the route order. The order determines the order of route execution. Routes with a lower order value are tried first.

For example:

```
[Route("/something-else", Order = 1)]
[Route("", Order = 2)]
public IActionResult Index(){

}
```

As an aside, I would strongly discourage you from serving the same page with multiple URLs. Google's indexing will give you worse ranking because of it. Instead, consider returning a redirect to the new URL instead.

Comment: Great answer, works as expected.
I will consider returning redirects like you suggested, but since the base url is the same with the new and the old web app, i don't think it would result in a penalty.

Comment: Google will still penalise you for having duplicate content on the same site.